# How to make QGIS Server recognize QGIS projects in a docker container?

Tags: docker, qgis

I need to launch a QGIS GUI into a browser from a docker container.

QGIS Desktop will launch in docker but the localhost and port find no service. QGIS Server does launch in docker but the browser landing page will not recognise there are any projects in the folder so stops there.

How can I direct my dockerised QGIS Server to find the QGIS project file?

So far I have tried the official QGIS image for QGIS Desktop, Kartoza's and camptocamp QGIS server images (https://github.com/camptocamp/docker-qgis-server) but find the same problem "This QGIS Server catalog does not contain any project" .

I was expecting to point my browser to the port and see QGIS.

The issue can be reproduced using this yaml: [Connect QGIS project in docker container with Postgres+Postgis in another docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62404763/connect-qgis-project-in-docker-container-with-postgrespostgis-in-another-docker)
or this one
https://hub.docker.com/r/kartoza/qgis-server/

I have changed the file path to one on C (in windows 10 path formatting) and docker recognizes the path as a valid. It correctly mounts the same folder in a container with RStudio. The folder has a copy of an OSM QGIS project.